# Where can I find or make a script for focus stacking using Raynox DCR 250?

Tags: canon, image-stacking, focus-stacking, raynox, programming

I am looking for a script for focus stacking with Raynox DCR 250. There is already default script there but it is linear and that is better suited to stock lenses and, with the Raynox 250 attached, I think it needs to exponential focus. Can anyone help me find such script or may be some setting with that default stacking script? I am using a Canon SX40.

Comment: When you say script...do you absolutely have to have a "script"? There are a few tools, in particular CombineZ, that will automatically align and blend a focus stack for you. CombineZ produces pretty darn good results as far as I've seen, too. Would that work?

Comment: What do you mean by exponential focus? You mean instead of incrementing in fixed focus increments, you want it to skip some focus intervals? Not sure what this will buy you except to skip a few shots?

Answer (score 2):

I have just written a focus-bracketing script for closeup lenses, including the Raynox 250.
Here is a link to my article, which contains documentation of the script as well as the script itself:
http://www.dpreview.com/articles/9780512447/focus-bracketing-scripts-for-macro-setting-and-for-closeup-lenses
Here is another link to some outdoor stacked images made using the script
http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3508821

Answer (score 1):

Really old thread.  Anyway, it seems people confuse 'stacking' and 'bracketing'.  Bracketing is used to capture a number of pictures of a scene while varying a parameter, exposure, focus, what have you.  Stacking is a post processing technique for combining bracketed photos to create HDR or increased depth of field, for instance.

For the original posters question, long time back i loaded up my Canon A720IS with the hacked CHDK firmware which facilitates scripting and wrote a script based on the  hyperfocal distances.  It worked ok and stacking the focus bracketed shots did result in enhanced DOF.

Some google fu came up with https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/UBASIC/Scripts/CanonA640:_Focus_Bracketing

Comment: The existing answers don't seem to confuse bracketing and stacking at all. The OP was asking about focus stacking for macro photography.

Comment: Thanks for response.. It's been long CHDK was fun. I was able to capture star trails. But I don't remember getting focus stacking work. I did manual shoot and stacking software to achieve some good result.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/ianoopkumar/8104934849/

Comment: Unless i'm completely misreading, the OP is asking to focus bracket using his camera and the Raynox lens.  Once you have a bunch of bracketed photos they get stacked in some PP software. From what i understand the PP stacking sw is independent of lens.  Stacking sw combines the in-focus areas of each picture in the bracketed series.

Comment: @scottbb The OP itself does seem to have trouble making the differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a special "script". There are some softwares that do the trick and are easy to use.

If by any chance you're using photoshop, this guide will help you:

[focus-stacking-made-easy-with-photoshop](http://photo.tutsplus.com/articles/post-processing-articles/focus-stacking-made-easy-with-photoshop/)

I was using it to stack 20 photos and it works great for me.